# How to disable proguard in Flutter after version 1.12?

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, build, proguard

I get a runtime error in my app when I activate the proguard obfuscation and shrinking as described in https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#enabling-proguard.

In the previous flutter versions I could simply comment out the minifyenabled and proguard commands. Since version 1.12 proguard is apparently enabled by default, as described by this issue:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/39986

It states that there should be a flag called "--proguard", but when I try to use it with the command "flutter build appbundle", it shows an error that this is an unknown argument.

Answer (score -1):

I found the correct flag to disable proguard for a Flutter build. It is called

```
--no-shrink
```

It is also printed when the "flutter build appbundle" command is executed with the help option.

Comment: Where would I add this flag? On the gradle file?

Comment: @Donki no I guess you have to include it at the end of build command. Like `flutter build appbundle --no-shrink`